# Importing matplotlib causes "int() argument must be a string" error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Python. A few days ago I installed Anaconda and PyCharm (on D disk), and I am trying to use the `matplotlib` package to plot one picture. When I click "run", I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\onedrive\OneDrive - mail.dlut.edu.cn\PyCharm\shock wave\P6.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2230, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 672, in __getitem__
    plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 247, in switch_backend
    switch_backend(candidate)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 267, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 268, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qtagg.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend_qt import (
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 73, in <module>
    _MODIFIER_KEYS = [
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 74, in <listcomp>
    (_to_int(getattr(_enum("QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier"), mod)),
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyboardModifier'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It looks like this is a bug in [`pyside6`](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/) v6.3.0**, one of the libraries `matplotlib` depends on for rendering plots; [here's the bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24155). It's a new bug, and it's already been fixed, so it's really bad luck that it got you!

**Solution:** the issue seems to be fixed in `pyside` version 6.4.0 (released 13 October), so one solution is to upgrade it, or you could downgrade, e.g. to version 6.2. Another solution is to try using another backend, because I think the problem only affects the Qt backend. (A `backend` is a rendering engine for `matplotlib` — [read all about them](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html).) It's easy to try this latter option, so let's start there.

#### Use another backend

Try this at the top of your script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
```

Or you can try others; [see this page for help.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html)

#### Up- or down-grade `pyside`

To handle this, you'll need to deal with ['virtual environments'](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). You may already be doing this. Environments let you have different versions of Python and different collections of packages for different projects you might be working on.

##### Fix the `base` environment...

When you install Anaconda, it made an environment called `base` that contains 'everything' in Anaconda (Python plus lots of libraries like `matplotlib`). You can upgrade the version of `pyside` in the `base` environment by opening an **Anaconda prompt** from the Start menu and typing this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyside==6.4.0
```

However, most programmers don't use their base environment and prefer to manage an environment specific to their project. If you are doing this, or want to give it a try, read on.

##### ...or make a new environment

Alternatively, to make a new environment, open an Anaconda prompt and type this but replace `MYENV` with a short suitable name for the environment:

```
conda create -n MYENV python=3.10 pyside=6.4.0 anaconda
```

Or you can replace `anaconda` with a list of the packages you want, like `jupyter scipy networkx` or whatever.

You would then start using this environment with `conda activate MYENV` and your script or notebook should run in there no problem.

Comment: I had tried your advice and it's very useful to use the first method. And I had also tried the second method, however, it tells me "failed with initial frozen solve". Whatever, I have solved this problem and thanks for your help!

Comment: I found similar issue when I tried to use matplotlib, but "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyboardModifier'" still occurs even when I have upgraded pyside6 to 6.4.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
When Update pyside >=6.4.0, You alse need update matplotlib to 3.6.2

**Reason:**
[Qt for Python Release: 6.4 The new Enum system](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-release-6.4-is-finally-here)

**Sloution**
update matplotlib to 3.6.2

**Refer** [github Isue#24332](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24332)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Matt Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20623798/matt-hall).
The problem with pyside and matplotlib-3.6.0 can be solved by doing:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.8.0
```