# ERROR: "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyboardModifier'" while using matplotlib in pyside6 GUI application

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside6

I am coding a Pyside6 based GUI program to show wav/mp3 wavform figure with librosa, add import list as following,

```
#import lib 
import librosa
import librosa.display

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#code in WavformShow.py

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 2))
        librosa.display.waveshow(data,sample_rate,offset=0.0)
```

However, when I run the script, an error message is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainFrame_v8.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ClassicAudio.WavformShow import *
  File "E:\Code\Qt-proj\Pyside6UI\ClassicAudio\WavformShow.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
  File "C:\Users\rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .backend_qtagg import (    # noqa: F401, E402 # pylint: disable=W0611
  File "C:\Users\rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qtagg.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend_qt import (
  File "C:\Users\rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 73, in <module>
    _MODIFIER_KEYS = [
  File "C:\Users\rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 74, in <listcomp>
    (_to_int(getattr(_enum("QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier"), mod)),
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyboardModifier'
```

plus,

1. I have tried 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt', but same issue happened;
2. also, tried with 'matplotlib.use('tkagg')', which may choose tkagg backend, and tigger a independent show window, which is not my expectation(a picutre show in a wrapper).

Comment: As the name suggests, `backend_qt5agg` forces the Qt5 backend, but you're using Qt6. Try to change to the basic `backend_qt5agg`, and remember that you should also always import the Qt binding *before* matplotlib to avoid conflicts in case both PyQt and PySide (which are **not** compatible) are installed.

Comment: Actually, I have tried "from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas" or "from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg", however, same error information is printed.

Comment: Then, if you have PySide6.3, it's a bug, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74112099): you either up/downgrade PySide or you use another backend.

Comment: Thanks, musicamante. Issue happened when my pyside6 version has been upgraded to 6.4.0.1, so, now I will try other workarounds.